# Combining multiple "transform" entries in Less

Tags: css, combinations, less, css-transforms

I have two mixins which both convert to `-webkit-transform`:

```
.rotate(@deg) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(@deg);
}

.scale(@factor) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(@factor);
}
```

When I use them together:

```
div {
  .rotate(15deg);
  .scale(2);
}
```

... they (as expected) show up as:

```
div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
}
```

This doesn't seem to be valid CSS as the second has precedence over the first; the first is discarded. To combine `transform` entries it should be:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(2);
```

How can I accomplish such CSS to be generated by LESS, i.e. multiple `transform` entries that are combined correctly?

Comment: could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Alp: I'm not sure how where to put LESS code there. It looks like only CSS and SCSS are available. Placing a `<link>` to an external `.less` file gives a cross domain error.

Comment: I know it's kind of late, but the reason for the cross domain error is your server was not sending the correct CORS headers back. JSFiddle did not have has to do anything in that case, unless you wanted it to send authentication, which you would have to coordinate with JSFiddle to do, and probably wouldn't have been worth it to do.

Comment: @TylerH - I'm going to revert your edit. Less is already specified as tag of the Q so it should not appear in the title (also note the official name is Less not LESS).

Comment: @seven-phases-max The edit is to make it clear for searches on the subject that this question is not useful for non-Less applications. Otherwise I would agree that Less shouldn't be in the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provide your transforms as arguments for a single mixin:

```
.transform(@scale,@rotate) {
  -webkit-transform: @arguments;
}
```

<del>I guess, you also could achieve to concatenate your separate mixins into one with the help of guards, but I'm not entirely sure;)</del>

I think you are not able to achieve this in another way, since the parser would have to modify code afterwards which should not be possible.

Comment: Thanks, this works, though I'm not fully enthousiastic about it. But it will do if there is no other option.

Comment: I filed a request [here](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/700), but there hasn't been much progress.

Comment: hm, what ninique stated is basically the same thing which I proposed. I don't think they will implement such a feature because it contradicts the paradigm of the overriding nature of css and would call for lots of trouble...

Comment: Yeah, in my opinion it is actually a mistake of CSS not to define `rotation: 25deg; scale: 2;` or something along the lines of that.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from Less v1.7.0, [merging property values](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-space) with a space separator is possible and there is no need to club the two mixins into one.

The below Less code

```
.rotate(@deg) {
  -webkit-transform+_: rotate(@deg);
}

.scale(@factor) {
  -webkit-transform+_: scale(@factor);
}

div{
    .rotate(45deg);
    .scale(1.5);
}
```

will compile into the following CSS:

```
div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: Is there something similar in Sass (SCSS)?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a simple way over it, create a div container for the eleemnt, and apply first transform to the cntainer, leaving the second one for the element itself

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems getting @arguments to work. I used the [@rest variable](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) which did the trick

**LESS example:**

```
.transform(@rest...) {
   transform: @rest;
   -ms-transform: @rest;
   -webkit-transform: @rest;
}

.someClass{
   .transform(translate3D(0,0,0),scale(1,1));
}

.otherClass{
   .transform(translate3D(0,0,0),rotate(1,1));
}

.anotherClass{
   .transform(rotate(1,1));
}
```

**Output CSS:**

```
.someClass {
  transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
}
.otherClass {
  transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) rotate(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) rotate(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0) rotate(1, 1);
}
.anotherClass {
  transform: rotate(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1, 1);
}
```